# Bootstrap : dropdown() function not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I need your help to complete my Bootstrap JS integration.
I'm trying to open a "dropdown-menu" using dropdown JS function.
Guess what? It doesn't work...

Goal : open a dropdown menu (always the same) using differents links on the same page

How would you achieve this please ?

Bootply exemple (current code, not working) : http://www.bootply.com/VlRnZNXoUK

Thanks a lot,
Have a nice day,

Omageus

Comment: ...You dont have a dropdown menu to show in your markup.

Comment: <h1 class="link2" data-toggle="dropdown">link 2 (not working)</h1> .Now it works on both links..

Comment: Well, thanks, it works when I add data-toggle="dropdown". But I would like to edit my "dropdown class" (I've multiple dropdown items on my page). This approach always refer to "dropdown-menu". Any chance to find a workaround with the JS function?

Comment: Adding a "data-toggle" doesn't work is parent isn't near : http://www.bootply.com/vTKRZeqHJh